# Remove the rectangle around desktop icon when selected

Tags: windows, desktop, icons

Is there a way to remove the rectangle around desktop icons, whithin the aero theme?

Take a look at this icon. You can see the box around the icon when it's highlighted:

[image: Skype icon]

Now, take a look at the same icon with the classic theme enabled, no box around the icon:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the rectangle without changing to classic mode?

Answer (score 0):

The solution below recommends creating a custom theme instead of editing your current one.

- http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/253264-remove-icon-hover-highlight.html

Comment: It is not applicable to the Classic theme.